# How to make slider menu for all activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, slider, navigation-drawer

Hi I had created an android app with slider menu using the link https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu .Nowcan you explain how to add menus to sided window and how will it load navigated page to the MainActivity. for example If I have my A activity in front I slide and choose Activity B from slide menu how will it load Activity B in front.

Also do I need to add sliding window to all activity to have navigation or is there any way to get it done for all activity from a single place.﻿

Also How can I make actions on slided view ??

here is my code

```
    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.login);
```

my screen is looks as in the images[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by creating your own activity class that extends Android's activity.

create a new class, let's say you chose to name it "MyActivity", the code should look as follows

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    SlidingMenu menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup the sliding menu
        menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    }

}
```

then extend all your other activities from this class, for example

```
public class LoginActivity extends MyActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Now you can call menu
        //menu.doSomething....
        menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.login);
    }

}
```

Comment: i used  menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.login); so how can i make action in login page ?? Need to create a new activity ??

Comment: But I need to make action in login page like button click etc from mainactivity.is it possible??

Comment: Yes it is, you'll be able to access the menu variable from all the activities that extend MyActivity, then you can use it as you like.

Comment: its not working..I think U didn't get me.I want to load some contents from web like load an image to my login page when it appears. So I need to code on mainactivity right??

Comment: simply i need to load a webcontent (webview) in slide content So where should i coded ??

Comment: code it in MyActivity, and then you can access it and edit it from the other activities.

Comment: no its not working when I called login widget ids into main activity

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking for Navigation Drawer.Please refer http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html